# Do we need ARM build for arduino while interfacing R-pi and arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, raspberrypi

I wonder whats ARM build for Linux? Do we really need ARM build when we work with arduino? I need to integrate arduino and raspberry pi over wi-fi, I don't know whether I need ARM in this case. Also any quick learning tutorial for interfacing two of these hardware is appreciable

A newbie to Arduino. I hope fun learning with it

Comment: The arm build contains arm binaries for the compiler. Are you running the IDE on the pi?

Comment: To interface the two grasp the usb cable firmly by the plug and insert into the usb socket.

Comment: please tell me why we need ARM while working with arduino. I have to get the logs of arduino based sensor nodes on raspberry pi. in this case, do i need ARM ?

Comment: I need to interface over the wireless medium

Comment: And I asked a question. ARE YOU RUNNING THE IDE ON THE PI?

Comment: Nope. Not running on pi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ARM build of the IDE is for running the IDE on ARM systems. If you want to run the IDE on the pi then you need the arm build. However if you want to run the IDE on your PC then you need the IDE build that matches the architecture of your pc.

There are a million and one ways of communicating wirelessly between an Arduino and a pi.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now i am at ease. R pi is ARM system and we need ARM build for that. right>

Comment: Only if you want to compile Arduino sketches using the pi.